# Get 'NSInvalidArgumentException' 'Attempt to insert non-property list object when saving class type array to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, userdefaults

In below TableViewController, I'm trying to store a class type array(playList) to UserDefaults then retrieve it in each table cell. But as opening this table View, app is crashed with 
`"Terminating app due to uncaught exception '**NSInvalidArgumentException**', reason: '**Attempt to insert non-property list object** (
    "LocalMusicPlayer.SongData"
) for key playList'", but if the data is simply string array, it works.

Just come to `UserDefaults` today, want to ask if it is not supported for storing class type data or some extra method like `defaults.object(forKey: "playList")` should be involved?

Another question is that in real implementation, if I should put initialization of `UserDefaults` operations to some other files' init() but not under viewDidLoad() of a View. Your help is appreciated!

/// Well, below is my SongData and TableView file.

/// 9.4, 2019, involve NSObject and NSCoding, it is working now.

```
import UIKit

class SongData: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var songName: String
    var artistName: String
    var albumName: String
    var albumArtwork: UIImage
    var url: URL

    init(songName: String, artistName: String, albumName: String, albumArtwork: UIImage, url: URL) {
        self.songName = songName
        self.artistName = artistName
        self.albumName = albumName
        self.albumArtwork = albumArtwork
        self.url = url
    }

    // MARK: -NSCoding
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(songName, forKey: "songName")
        aCoder.encode(artistName, forKey: "artistName")
        aCoder.encode(albumName, forKey: "albumName")
        aCoder.encode(albumArtwork, forKey: "albumArtwork")
        aCoder.encode(url, forKey: "url")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        songName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "songName") as! String
        artistName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "artistName") as! String
        albumName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "albumName") as! String
        albumArtwork = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "albumArtwork") as! UIImage
        url = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "url") as! URL
    }
}
```

/// Table View

```
import UIKit

class PlaylistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var song: SongData?
    var playList = [SongData]()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playList.append(SongData(songName: "You Belong With Me", artistName: "Tylor Swift", albumName: "Love", albumArtwork: UIImage(named: "Apple")!, url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/14E1BC3D-65A6-4854-9CD6-A8740265F341/Documents/Just%20Dance.mp3")))
        playList.append(SongData(songName: "Just Dance", artistName: "Lady Gaga", albumName: "Love", albumArtwork: UIImage(named: "Apple")!, url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/14E1BC3D-65A6-4854-9CD6-A8740265F341/Documents/Just%20Dance.mp3")))

        let encodedData = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: playList, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "playList")
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return playList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return "PLAYLISTS"
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playListLabelCell", for: indexPath)

        let decoded = defaults.object(forKey: "playList") as! Data
        let decodedTeams = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(decoded) as! [SongData]
        cell.textLabel?.text = decodedTeams[indexPath.row].songName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = decodedTeams[indexPath.row].artistName
        cell.imageView?.image = decodedTeams[indexPath.row].albumArtwork

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: @vadian, yes, I found this answer, is trying to connect with my code, but no result yet, so I raise this question, my bad.

Comment: You have to serialize your class to `Data`. As an `UIImage` instance is included I'd recommend to make the class a subclass of `NSObject`, adopt `NS(Secure)Coding` and implement the protocol methods. This is described in the duplicate. [Here are many other related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%7Bswift%7D+Attempt+to+insert+non-property+list+object)

Comment: @vadian, well my purpose is to persistently save music playlist in my app. And I think to only store the url, which is unique could be the idea. Because UserDefaults may not have the size capability for UIImage, then I could retrieve the UIImage, and albumName... from where url = "". Above example just a 1st try to see if UserDefaults is working.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose to comment on that original question but without enough reputation:( Today I Inherit `NSObject` and `NSCoding` for my SongData class and implement the protocol methods, it is working now, I could retrieve the songName, artwork... from the decoder. Just 1 question, if it is ideal to save the music artwork to `UserDefaults`? e.g. hundreds of songs with artworks may take a big size,  if `UserDefaults` could handle it nicely and not affect the performance of App?

Comment: `UserDefaults` for large data sets is bad practice. There is CoreData, MYSQL or other third-party databases.

Comment: Yeah, I consider to use Core Data & SQLite on yesterday, but I try the NSCoding method firstly in this morning. Will look into about how to implement them on my App after finishing all the viewController design. Thanks for it.